# Why is Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR not listed in google developer SensorEvent references?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Little bit wired. I want to use a Step Detector that is build in at KitKat. So its API Level 19.

In documentation on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

There is the Step Counter Sensor listed, but... why not here at the SensorEvents?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

I have the API Level on the website selected to 19. I heared values[0] is the right, but why isnt it documented?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the reason. But it seems you could access the value through `(int)sensorEvent.values[0]`. It works.
The same for the `TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` as follows [Android TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR while screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011366/android-type-step-detector-while-screen-off).