# Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR not found on android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am developing a pedometer android application and for that i used Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR which is available from android KitKat.
Everything was working fine at Nexus 5 and Samsung Alpha but then i tested my application on Moto G(Lollipop) and Nexus 4(Lollipop),
both the device are returning null when i am trying to get sensor of Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR type.

Here is my code:

```
 private boolean checkSensorAvailability() {
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    if(sensor==null){return false;}

    return true;
}
```

As per my knowledge this sensor required Accelerometer in Device. 
Which is available in both devices.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: I am using Nexus 5, nexus 4, Samsung Galaxy Alpha, Moto G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some devices simply refused that (full wake-up) functionality.

> The problem is power consumption. If the phone wakes up the application processor every time a step occurred, it will draw more power and could lead to poor battery life. With your phone, the manufacturer has made a decision NOT to support a "wake-up" version of the sensor that would turn the phone on when a step is detected.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071354/603270

As a workaround, I recommend looking at https://github.com/j4velin/Pedometer/blob/master/src/main/java/de/j4velin/pedometer/SensorListener.java

```
public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent event) {
    steps = (int) event.values[0];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Then how to resolve this problem? should i use TYPE_ACCELEROMETER type?

Comment: See if `onSensorChanged()` is called when screen is off and if `(int) event.values[0]` is a valid number of steps: https://github.com/j4velin/Pedometer/blob/master/src/main/java/de/j4velin/pedometer/SensorListener.java (I haven't tried this code but it's the only workaround I know of).

Comment: @shkscheider Thanks for your attention but my problem starts when i try to get sensor as in the mentioned post 
sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, 5 * MICROSECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);

So this guy is getting sensor using sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

while i am getting null

Answer (score 1):

Not every device will support steps sensors:

From Docs:

> Both step sensors are hardware dependent (Nexus 5 is the first device
>   to support them), so you should check for availability with
>   hasSystemFeature(), using the FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR and
>   FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER constants.

Found here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

Answer (score 0):

As the Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) states:

Both step sensors are hardware dependent (Nexus 5 is the first device to support them), so you should check for availability with hasSystemFeature(), using the FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR and FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER constants.

Hence Nexus 4 and Moto G2 won't support it. You should check for other devices.